# How to express "Eternal/Endless Love" on an engraved bracelet

Tags: words

In a fanfiction i am writing, one of the characters who was born in Japan gives her girlfriend a bracelet she had made, as a sign of her nationality there is an engraving in japanese which, when her girlfriend asks the meaning she replies

> "It's Nanoha loves Feito Forever"

which is actually a reference to when 2 people write their initials in a heart like this

```
   ____    ____
  /    \  /    \
 /      \/      \
/                \
\      N T       /
 \              /
  \     +      /
   \          /
    \ F T H  /
     \      /
      \    /
       \  /
        \/
```

N T = Nanoha Takamachi

F T H = Fate Testarossa Harlaown (Nanoha says Feito)

when i use google translate to find Loves i get [愛](https://translate.google.com/#en/ja/loves), using the Nanoha Wikia for [Nanoah's](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Nanoha) and [Fate's](http://nanoha.wikia.com/wiki/Fate) names in japanese i get

> なのは愛 フェイト

since i'm a stricter for accuracy with these things i am wondering if this correct? if not what would be the correct way of express what i am trying to achieve

Comment: You can't just substitute Japanese words for English words.  Japanese is a different language with its own grammar and vocabulary.

Comment: Changed the subject to a more specific one. I think this is a meaningful question for those who know the basics of Japanese grammar, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, every language has peculiar vocabulary when it comes to memorials, ceremonies, gravestones, etc. Don't believe Google Translate in such a case.

Second, Japanese people generally don't like engraving Japanese text on things like rings, bracelets, watches, etc. Sharing such items as the symbol of love or friendship is a common practice in Japan, but [using English alphabets is by far the commonest](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E3%83%96%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%20%E5%88%BB%E5%8D%B0):

> NANOHA LOVE FATE
>   NANOHA ♥ FATE
>   FOREVER LOVE / NANOHA & FATE / 2014

I think these may look somewhat weird to native English speakers, but that's how it is.  Using kanji makes even less sense when the present is for a foreigner.

If you insist that you need a *Japanese* expression which is not understandable by Fate, here are the samples:

> 2人の愛が永遠に続きますように　Futari no Ai ga Eien ni Tsuzukimasu yoni.
>   May our love last forever.
>
> 愛は永遠に　Ai wa Eien ni.
>   Love (lasts) forever.
>
> 永遠の愛をここに誓う　Eien no Ai wo Koko ni Chikau.
>   We herein pledge eternal love.

These expressions are frequently seen on Japanese [絵馬](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ema_(Shinto)).

Anything shorter than these, like simply putting "愛 (love)", would be very strange to native Japanese people. But as you are writing to English-speaking audience, you may not have to be too strict. For example, [kanji tattoos](http://www.japan-talk.com/jt/new/kanji-tattoos) by westerners are always weird to Japanese (even if they're in perfect Japanese), but we just can't stop them.